# Find parabola by set of points in python

Tags: python, interpolation, approximation

I have a set of points like

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..]
Y = [9, 7, 5, 3, 5, ..]
```

I need to find interpolation parabola for Y like it's done my MNK method for lines. Is there any functions in NumPy maybe? Im not really good at therms of quadratic approximation so couldn't find it by myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out `numpy.polyfit:
Fit a polynomial p(x) = p[0] * x**deg + ... + p[deg] of degree deg to points (x, y). 
Returns a vector of coefficients p that minimises the squared error.`

It does exactly what I need, more info on [numpy.polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).